Applications of the EGZ theorem
I was wondering whether there were some applications of the Erdős–Ginzburg–Ziv theorem in multiple areas of mathematics (and I am not talking about problems that can only be solved using this theorem but rather where an alternate solution is possible with EGZ). I only found some direct applications and one other interesting application discussed by Fedor Petrov. Does anyone have an idea ?

What is the cool application discussed by Fedor Petrov?
